# meteor collection find, console vs. terminal

Tags: meteor

*In /lib/collections/task.js*:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
```

*In server code*:

```
Meteor.publish('tasks', function(){
  return Tasks.find();
});
```

*In client code*:

```
Meteor.subscribe('tasks');
```

When I run this command `Tasks.find().count()`

The Browser console outputs 1, but the  `meteor:PRIMARY> db.Tasks.find().count()`
reports 0.

I expected to see one records in both.
 Why it is not? Thanks

Comment: does Tasks.find() works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because it should be `db.tasks.find().count()`
not `db.Tasks.find().count()`

Per your declaration `Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');` in Mongo, the collection is named `'tasks'`